# Messages do not reach subscriber in masstransit

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, esb, masstransit

I have two projects run in different processes and RMQ deployed on a separate machine.

Here is my publisher code

```
Bus.Initialize(config =>
            {
                config.UseRabbitMq();
                config.UseRabbitMqRouting();
                config.UseControlBus();
                config.EnableMessageTracing();
                config.EnableRemoteIntrospection();
                config.ReceiveFrom("rabbitmq://debug:debug@data.sampleserver.com:5672/bus/response-queue");
            });

            Console.ReadLine();

            int i = 0;

            while (i < 20)
            {
                i += 1;

                Console.WriteLine("Publishing...");
                Bus.Instance.Publish(new Message
                    {
                        Body = String.Format("Body = {0}", i)
                    });

                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
```

Here is my subscriber code:

```
Bus.Initialize(config =>
            {
                config.UseRabbitMq();
                config.UseRabbitMqRouting();
                config.ReceiveFrom("rabbitmq://debug:debug@data.sampleserver.com:5672/bus/response-queue");
                config.UseControlBus();
                config.EnableMessageTracing();
                config.UseHealthMonitoring(10);
            });

            var service = HostFactory.New(config =>
            {
                config.SetServiceName("survey");
                config.SetDisplayName("survey");
                config.SetDescription("Survey service");

                config.Service<Service>(s =>
                {
                    s.ConstructUsing(sv => new Service(Bus.Instance));
                    s.WhenStarted(sv => sv.Start());
                    s.WhenStopped(sv => sv.Stop());
                });
            });

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    service.Run();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }
            });
```

In the server, I've the following subscription:

```
public Service(IServiceBus serviceBus)
        {
            _serviceBus = serviceBus;
            _serviceBus.SubscribeHandler<Message>(Handle);
        }

        void Handle(Message message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Receive a new message with body {0}", message.Body);
        }
```

When I send a set of messages by publisher, only few of them successfully reach subscriber. Most of them fall in response-queue-error.

I am new with masstransit and I do not understand what's going on inside it and do not understand how I can figure it out.

Anything you can recommend in this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I notice that the publisher and subscriber in your example are listening on the same queue. In general, you should have every endpoint on a separate queue. MassTransit will take care of routing the messages based on the type.

Comment: See also http://masstransit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration/gotchas.html#trying-to-share-a-queue and http://masstransit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration/config_api.html#basic-options